# LLN and RPL Simulator?

Tags: 6lowpan, contiki

I'm working on a project which is about designing an IDS for RPL Protocol. In this project I have to simulate different types of attacks (e.g. Black hole Attack) and RPL Protocol. I saw on the Internet that Contiki OS and Cooja simulator have not been upgraded for 4 years. Do you have an alternative you can suggest?
Any Comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this 6tisch simulator that implements the whole protocol stack. It's written in Python. Might help.

https://bitbucket.org/6tisch/simulator

Cheers.